# Providing a default value parsing XML with ElementTree when findall() finds no match

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Very new to Python, and I am building a project to learn Python. The project involves XML parsing, for which I have used ElementTree.

This is the code I currently have:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree = etree.parse('ar.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

ns = {'nbb': 'http://www.nbb.be/be/fr/pfs/ci/2017-04-01'}

for ass in tree.findall("nbb:Assets[@contextRef='CurrentInstant']", ns):
    assets = ass.text

for pay in tree.findall("nbb:AmountsPayable[@contextRef='CurrentInstant']", ns):
    payables = pay.text

for prov in tree.findall("nbb:ProvisionsDeferredTaxes[@contextRef='CurrentInstant']", ns):
    provisions = prov.text

for cap in tree.findall("nbb:IssuedCapital[@contextRef='CurrentInstant']", ns):
    capital = cap.text

print assets
print payables
print provisions
print capital
```

For most XML files, this works perfectly fine.

However, some of the XML files for which I would like to use the code do not have the Element ("nbb:ProvisionsDeferredTaxes[@contextRef='CurrentInstant']", ns). In those cases, the following error shows up: name 'provisions' is not defined.

I need to use the variables to make calculations further down the code (for example: assets - provisions), and I would need the value of 'provisions' to be assigned to 0 in the XML files where there is no ("nbb:ProvisionsDeferredTaxes[@contextRef='CurrentInstant']", ns) Element.

How should I proceed?

Many thanks!

Comment: More important to use the title's space to include the essential elements of the question than the implementation language -- tags are used for display of and filtering by language, except where including the language in the title flows naturally (and fits easily). See [discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251861/14122).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for`/`else` clause provides one way to handle this:

```
for prov in tree.findall("nbb:ProvisionsDeferredTaxes[@contextRef='CurrentInstant']", ns):
    provisions = int(prov.text)
    break
else:
    provisions = 0
```

The `else` clause is run when `break` never takes place.

---

You could also initialize the value, and reassign in the loop:

```
provisions = 0
for prov in tree.findall("nbb:ProvisionsDeferredTaxes[@contextRef='CurrentInstant']", ns):
    provisions = int(prov.text)
```